# In relation to acumatica, how do I allow people to enter text on multiple lines in the description within the grid section of a Tab?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm trying to get the description field to look like what is shown below. I have already looked at the question I have linked, and it mentions that I need to edit the Default folder on my computer which is part of the existing instance.

[How can I make an Acumatica, multiline PXGridColumn display new lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452489/how-can-i-make-an-acumatica-multiline-pxgridcolumn-display-new-lines)

However, I don't currently have access to any of those folders as I can only access the Acumatica system when I log in on the website.

I have also tried the second answer that was provided in the linked question: [How can I make an Acumatica, multiline PXGridColumn display new lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452489/how-can-i-make-an-acumatica-multiline-pxgridcolumn-display-new-lines)

It mentions that I need to change the WrapText value of the Grid to True, which I have done already, but it still doesn't do what I would like.

Ideally, I would like people to be able to press Enter and make a new line instead of pressing Enter and landing on the next cell. Is there a way to make the description field act like a text box?

[image: Description value over multiple lines]

Comment: Why is this post tagged with c#? Is there any relevant c# code about your issue?

Comment: Well I figured there might be some kind of solution involving c# since trying to solve it without code hasn’t worked so far :)

Comment: @AndrewAiello - It sounds like you'd be customizing a SaaS instance. I'd recommend installing an instance locally and working with a customization until it is how you want it. This would give you access to the theme files from example 1. You can then include the customized files in the customization which you can upload to the SaaS instance and publish.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Deetz! I'll give that a go and get back to you about how it went :D